# Cannot access a dictionary created with TouchJSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, touchjson

I am trying to use TouchJSON and here is what I have done to test it :

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"firtname\": \"Matthieu\",\"lastname\": \"Ravey\",\"age\": 22}";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];

NSString *firstname = [dictionary objectForKey:@"firstname"];

NSLog(@"%@", firstname);
```

But it logs `null` instead of Matthieu, what am I missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your json string - `NSString *jsonString = @"{\"firtname\": \"Matthieu\",\"lastname\": \"Ravey\",\"age\": 22}";` it says `firtstring`.

Try accessing this dictionary with same keys !

So the change would be -

`NSString *firstname = [dictionary objectForKey:@"firtname"];`